# Encrypted connectionstring in web.config in web application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, connection-string

In my web application, I have put encrypted password like:

```
<add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=abc;Initial Catalog=dms;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=****************" />
```

and at run time, I decrypt it and use it.
It works fine in all pages, but in 1 page it shows error like 
Login failed for user 'sa'.
there is no error anywhere. I debug many times, but still it continues.
Instead I use actual connection string it works fine.
what should I do?

Comment: Never **ever** put a password on the web, especially for the sa account.  Even if you know no one will ever be able to use, don't do it.  I've edited your post to mask the password - but I would advise you to delete your question and repost it, with the password masked.

Comment: Ok..thanks..i will keep this in mind